# Evaluate $\int\frac{2\cos^2x+2}{\sin^3x} \, \operatorname{d}\!x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Solving the Indefinite integral: 
$$\int\frac{2\cos^2x+2}{\sin^3x}\, \operatorname{d}\!x$$

What's the proper way of finding Indefinite integral in this one? can't get rid of either $\cos$ or $\sin$.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget that, if you are integrating with respect to $x$ then *you must* use $\operatorname{d}\!x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u=\cos x$ so $du=-\sin x dx$ and we have
$$\int\frac{2\cos^2 x+2}{\sin^3x}dx=-2\int\frac{u^2+1}{(1-u^2)^2}du=-\int\frac{du}{(1-u)^2}-\int\frac{du}{(u+1)^2}\\=-(1-u)^{-1}+(1+u)^{-1}+C=\frac{1}{1+\cos x}-\frac{1}{1-\cos x}+C=-2\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}+C$$

Comment: You might continue with combining and simplifying the $\cos$ terms.

Comment: @martycohen I edited my answer as you suggested but the simplification is a matter of taste and maybe there are people who prefer  write the final result with the function $\mathrm{cotan}$ :)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: See the general case below. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A good point for the next. Assume you have the following integral:
$$
\int R(\sin x,\cos x)dx
$$

If you have $$R(-\sin x,\cos x)\equiv-R(\sin x,\cos x)$$ then it is easier for us to set $\cos x=t$. And you can see this fact is satisfied for the integrand.

Comment: In fact I used this method that you mentioned and it's called Bioche's rules in the jargon of French mathematics (I have not seen it in English) see http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gles_de_Bioche and I hope you do not find a problem in the French language:)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Thanks for remarking that link. I'll try to get along French one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int\frac{2\cos^2 x + 2}{\sin^3 x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=2\int\frac{1+\cos^2 x}{\sin^4 x}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int\frac{1+\cos^2 x}{\left(1 - \cos^2 x\right)^2}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int\frac{1+\cos^2 x}{\left(\cos^2 x-1\right)^2}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int\frac{\cos^2 x\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)}{\cos^2 x\left(\cos x - \dfrac{1}{\cos x}\right)^{\!2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int\frac{1+\dfrac{1}{\cos^2x}}{\left(\cos x - \dfrac{1}{\cos x}\right)^{\!2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, set $u=\cos x - \dfrac{1}{\cos x}$ and $\mathrm{d}u = -\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\cos ^2 x}\right)\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$. Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=2\int-\dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{u}+C\\
&=\dfrac{2}{\cos x - \dfrac{1}{\cos x}}+C\\
&=\dfrac{2\cos x}{\cos^2 x - 1} + C\\
&=-\dfrac{2\cos x}{\sin^2 x} + C\\
\end{aligned}\\\\
$$
$$
\boxed{\displaystyle{\int\dfrac{2\cos^2 x + 2}{\sin^3 x}\,\mathrm{d}x = -2\csc x \cot x + C}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{4-2\sin^{2}(x)}{\sin^{3}(x)} \ dx  = 4\cdot \int\csc^{3}(x)\ dx -2 \int \csc(x) \ dx $$

Now you can integrate $\csc^{3}(x)$ by writing it as $\csc^{2}(x) \cdot \csc(x) = (\cot^{2}(x)-1)\cdot \csc(x)$